# C1 DataGrid Not Showing Bound Data

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I'm looking for basic ideas on what might be happening. I have bound data to a DataGrid that works fine on my local. Sometimes though, on the dev test server, the data does not display in the grids I made. Others work fine. On some machines these grids work fine. There are all of the rows that belong and the data is there underneath for use in everything, but it just isn't visible. As in the grid bound to 20 objects will have 20 completely blank rows that I can click on and use the SelectedItem property to get values from.

I've tried clearing out the cache many times. Resetting the ItemsSource property to null then the underlying data, and calling Refresh() on the grid. So, any ideas on why data that is bound might create a row but not have anything visible.

Below is an example of one of the grids. This grid has the first column set in the constructor and isn't bound. The top is on the server and the bottom is from my local host.

[image: Sever based and local version of the same grid]

Below is the XAML code for the grid in the picture. The object bound to is a list of class called AccountTypeGridClass. All properties are public strings with both gets and sets implemented as well as a property changed event being thrown. Though that isn't used.

```
<af:GroupHeader x:Name="AccountTypeHeader" Header="Account Type" Grid.Row="0" Margin="5" >
        <dataGrid:DataGridBase HorizontalAlignment="Left" x:Name="AccountTypeGrid" GridLinesVisibility="None"
                               RowBackground="White" 
                               HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" HeadersVisibility="Column"
                               CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserResizeRows="False"
                               SelectionMode="SingleRow" >

            <c1:C1DataGrid.Columns>

                <c1:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Type" Name="TypeColumn" Width="100">
                    <c1:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="3, 0, 0, 0" Text="Account Type" af:AutoToolTip.Active="True"  />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </c1:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </c1:DataGridTemplateColumn>

                <c1:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Code" Name="AccountTypeCodeColumn" Width="100">
                    <c1:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="3, 0, 0, 0" Text="{Binding AccountTypeCode}" af:AutoToolTip.Active="True" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </c1:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </c1:DataGridTemplateColumn>

                <c1:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Code Description" Name="AccountTypeCodeDescriptionColumn" Width="200">
                    <c1:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="3, 0, 0, 0" Text="{Binding AccountTypeCodeDescription}" af:AutoToolTip.Active="True" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </c1:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </c1:DataGridTemplateColumn>

            </c1:C1DataGrid.Columns>

        </dataGrid:DataGridBase>
    </af:GroupHeader>
```

Edit: I will update an answer once I can figure it out but the comment by curiousBoy put me on the right track. It seems to be the object the grid is bound to. Another way to describe the original problem is that it is like the columns in the grid were bound to the wrong column name on some of the machines. I've found a way that works that is very similar so I am trying to figure out what the difference actually is that caused this issue.

Comment: Screenshots would be more helpful to understand better (from local and dev test) .

Comment: Add a screenshot of one of the grids that has a static value for comparison. Double clicking brings up a dialog that gets it's initially set value from the grid's SelectedItem property and does so without issue in both cases.

Comment: Hope this helps your problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1683142/datagridview-rows-show-up-but-no-data   That looks kinda similar

Comment: Thanks for the link. It does sound very similar, but the methods for fixing it haven't provided any results.I think the biggest difference between the two is that my works on almost all other machines using either local host or the dev server. All except on my machine using the dev server now. Others had an issue before but refreshing seems to have fixed that.